# Uninstall Ubuntu from windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uninstall

I've dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my computer and I'm having trouble uninstalling Ubuntu.  I don't remember how I installed it but I've ruled some things out.

Most tutorials tell me to delete the disk partition through disk management in Windows, but when I check there, there's only the Windows partition.

This makes me think that I installed using Wubi, but when I go to uninstall Ubuntu as a program, its not listed in the programs list.

Anyone have any ideas how to uninstall ubuntu from windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your Windows installation CD or Ubuntu installation CD and format the partition from there(That is while installing). You don't need to proceed once formatted. Just go back and then use Disk Management in Windows to use your partition